# Оформление приложения, растяжение объектов в зависимости от экрана

Tags: python, ооп, классы, qlayout, pyqt6

Появилась проблема в том, что не понимаю как правильно расположить виджеты чтобы они растягивались. 
Вот в моем случае я хочу, чтобы условие не залезало на меню (фото). Очень много пытался играть с `QSizePolicy` и т.п вещами, но без толку.

Также как можно другие элементы растянуть до меню?
Обратите внимание на `QLineEdit` и `QTextEdit`.

[image: Фото приложения]

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы текст автоматически был адаптирован под размеры с левой стороны и справа? Вот пробовал `QTextEdit` использовать вместо `QLabel`, но также уходит в правую сторону.

Хочу обратить внимание на непонимание того факта, что я поставил выравнивание поверху и по правой части, но условие далеко не совсем сверху. 
Читал про какие-то пружины (визуально так выглядели) в *Qt Designer*, но я такое даже не использовал, не понимаю причины почему текст не под названием "Лабораторная работа 1".

```
import sys

from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from tabdemo import TabWidget
from tasks import TaskChooser


class DlgMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    """
    Главный класс, здесь описывается основное окно, с которым взаимодействуем.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._init_ui()  # установка параметров для приложения
        self._create_tabs_vertical(6)  # создание количества пунктов в боковом меню
        self._create_combobox()  # создание выпадающего списка
        self._create_question()
        self._create_input_output_data()

        self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self._update_condition)
        self.combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self._update_condition)

    def _init_ui(self):
        """
        Метод для инициализации параметров приложения
        """
        self.setWindowTitle("Ковалев Данил ВКБ22")  # установка названия приложения
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icons8-окно-приложения-96.png"))  # установка окна приложения
        self.resize(800, 500)  # Размеры по умолчанию при запуске
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Cantrell', 11))  # Установка шрифта и размеров
        self._center()  # Центрирование приложение при запуске

    def _center(self):
        """
        Метод, который центрует положения появления окна при запуске.
        """
        qr = self.frameGeometry()  # размеры нашего окна
        cp = QtGui.QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def _create_tabs_vertical(self, n):
        """
        Создание вертикального меню, где находятся лабораторные работы
        """
        self.tabs = TabWidget()
        self.tabs.create_tabs(n)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)

    def _create_combobox(self):
        """
        Создание выпадающего списка, предположительно должен находится в правом верхнем угле
        """
        self.combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()  # создание выпадающего списка, гле будут задания
        self.combobox.addItems(["Задание 1", "Задание 2", "Задание 3",
                                "Задание 4"])  # в каждой лабораторной 4 задания, поэтому везде будет так

        self.tabs.layout.addWidget(self.combobox,
                                   alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)

    def _create_question(self):
        """
        Создание места для условия, динамически должен обновляться в зависимости от выбора в combobox и TabWidget
        """
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            "Напишите программу для решения примера. Есть переменные: a,b,c,k: Предусмотрите деление на 0. "
            "\nВсе необходимые переменные вводите ниже.")
        self.tabs.layout.addWidget(self.label,
                                   alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)

    def _create_input_output_data(self):
        self.input_data = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.input_data.setPlaceholderText("Input data: ")

        self.output_data = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.output_data.setPlaceholderText("Output data: ")
        self.output_data.setReadOnly(True)

        splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Vertical)
        splitter.addWidget(self.input_data)
        splitter.addWidget(self.output_data)

        self.tabs.layout.addWidget(splitter,
                                   alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight)

    def _update_condition(self):
        current_laboratory = self.tabs.currentIndex() + 1
        current_number_question = self.combobox.currentIndex() + 1
        condition = TaskChooser(current_laboratory, current_number_question).condition
        self.label.setText(condition)
        self.input_data.clear()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        """
        Диалоговое окно, оно появляется, когда пользователь хочет закрыть приложение
        """
        res = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, "Выход", "Вы точно уверены, что хотите выйти? ")
        event.accept() if res == 16384 else event.ignore()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dlg_window = DlgMain()
    dlg_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**tabdemopy**:

```
""" 
 Здесь описана логика создания бокового меню 
 Ответ, с которого получилась реализация: https://inlnk.ru/QwLLpD 
 """ 
 __all__ = ["TabWidget"] 
  
 from PyQt6 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore 
  
  
 class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar): 
  
     def tabSizeHint(self, index): 
         s = QtWidgets.QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index) 
         s.transpose() 
         return s 
  
     def paintEvent(self, event): 
         painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self) 
         opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTab() 
  
         for i in range(self.count()): 
             self.initStyleOption(opt, i) 
             painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.ControlElement.CE_TabBarTabShape, opt) 
             painter.save() 
  
             s = opt.rect.size() 
             s.transpose() 
             r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), s) 
             r.moveCenter(opt.rect.center()) 
             opt.rect = r 
  
             c = self.tabRect(i).center() 
             painter.translate(c) 
             painter.rotate(90) 
             painter.translate(-c) 
             painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.ControlElement.CE_TabBarTabLabel, opt) 
             painter.restore() 
  
  
 class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget): 
     def __init__(self, num_lab): 
         super().__init__() 
  
         self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(f"Лабораторная работа {num_lab}") 
         self.label.setStyleSheet(""" 
             font-size: 24px; 
         """) 
         self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self) 
         self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 
                               alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop) 
  
  
 class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget): 
     def __init__(self, parent=None): 
         super().__init__(parent) 
         self.setTabBar(TabBar(self)) 
  
         self.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.TabPosition.West) 
         self.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Cantrell', 11)) 
         self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self) 
  
     def create_tabs(self, count): 
         for i in range(1, count + 1): 
             self.addTab(Widget(i), QtGui.QIcon("chemistry.png"), f"Лабораторная работа {i}")
```

Я думаю, что tasks не сильно нужен. Я старался сделать так, чтобы выбор заданий был здесь, так как много импортов. Переносы вручную, то есть добавление "\n" в условия не помогает.

**tasks.py**

```
__all__ = ["TaskChooser"] 
  
 from programming_languages.first_laba_lang.tutor import first_question as first_laboratory_first_question 
 from programming_languages.first_laba_lang.tutor import second_question as first_laboratory_second_question 
 from programming_languages.first_laba_lang.tutor import third_question as first_laboratory_third_question 
 from programming_languages.first_laba_lang.tutor import last_question as first_laboratory_fourth_question 
  
 from programming_languages.second_laba_lang.main import first_question as second_laboratory_first_question 
 from programming_languages.second_laba_lang.main import second_question as second_laboratory_second_question 
 from programming_languages.second_laba_lang.main import third_question as second_laboratory_third_question 
 from programming_languages.second_laba_lang.main import fourth_question as second_laboratory_fourth_question 
  
 from programming_languages.third_laba_lang.main import first_question as third_laboratory_first_question 
 from programming_languages.third_laba_lang.main import second_question as third_laboratory_second_question 
 from programming_languages.third_laba_lang.main import third_question as third_laboratory_third_question 
 from programming_languages.third_laba_lang.main import fourth_question as third_laboratory_fourth_question 
  
 from programming_languages.fourth_laba_lang.main import first_question as fourth_laboratory_first_question 
 from programming_languages.fourth_laba_lang.main import second_question as fourth_laboratory_second_question 
 from programming_languages.fourth_laba_lang.main import third_question as fourth_laboratory_third_question 
 from programming_languages.fourth_laba_lang.main import fourth_question as fourth_laboratory_fourth_question 
  
 from programming_languages.fifth_laba_lang.main import first_question as fifth_laboratory_first_question 
 from programming_languages.fifth_laba_lang.main import second_question as fifth_laboratory_second_question 
 from programming_languages.fifth_laba_lang.main import third_question as fifth_laboratory_third_question 
 from programming_languages.fifth_laba_lang.main import fourth_question as fifth_laboratory_fourth_question 
  
 dictionary = { 
     "Лабораторная работа 1 Подзадача 1": ( 
         "Напишите программу для решения примера. Есть переменные: a,b,c,k: Предусмотрите деление на 0. " 
         "\nВсе необходимые переменные вводите ниже. ", first_laboratory_first_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 1 Подзадача 2": ("Дан произвольный список, содержащий и строки, и числа. \n" 
                                           "Выведите все четные элементы построчно. ", first_laboratory_second_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 1 Подзадача 3": ("Дан произвольный список, содержащий только числа. \n " 
                                           "Выведите результат сложения чисел больше 10. ", 
                                           first_laboratory_third_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 1 Подзадача 4": ("Дан произвольный список, содержащий только числа. \n" 
                                           "Выведите максимальное число", first_laboratory_fourth_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 2 Подзадача 1": ("Пусть задано некоторое число my_number. \n" 
                                           "Запрашивайте у пользователя вводить число user_number до тех пор, " 
                                           "пока оно не будет меньше my_number", second_laboratory_first_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 2 Подзадача 2": ("Пусть задан список, содержащий строки. \n" 
                                           "Выведите построчно все строки размером от 5 до 10 символов. ", 
                                           second_laboratory_second_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 2 Подзадача 3": ("Сгенерируйте и выведите случайную строку, состоящую из 5 символов, \n" 
                                           "содержащую только заглавные буквы русского алфавита", 
                                           second_laboratory_third_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 2 Подзадача 4": ("Пусть дана строка. На основе данной строки сформируйте новую, " 
                                           "содержащую только цифры \nВыведите новую строку. ", 
                                           second_laboratory_fourth_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 3 Подзадача 1": ("Пусть дана строка, состоящая из слов, пробелов и знаков препинания. " 
                                           "\n" 
                                           "На основании этой строки создайте новую (и выведите её на консоль) \n" 
                                           "Содержащую только слова больше 5 символов.", 
                                           third_laboratory_first_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 3 Подзадача 2": ("Пусть дана строковая переменная, содержащая информацию о студентах: " 
                                           "\n" 
                                           "my_string='Ф;И;О;Возраст;Категория;_Иванов;Иван;Иванович;23 года'", 
                                           third_laboratory_second_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 3 Подзадача 3": ("Дана строка из прошлого задания. Выведите построчно информацию о " 
                                           "студентах, чья фамилия 'Петров'", third_laboratory_third_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 3 Подзадача 4": ("Пусть дана строка произвольной длины. Выведите информацию о том, " 
                                           "сколько в ней символов и сколько строк.", third_laboratory_fourth_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 4 Подзадача 1": ("Пусть дана матрица чисел размером NxN. Представьте данную матрицу в " 
                                           "виде списка.\nВыведите результат сложения всех элементов матрицы.", 
                                           fourth_laboratory_first_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 4 Подзадача 2": ("Пусть дан список из 10 элементов. Удалите первые 2 элемента и " 
                                           "добавьте 2 новых.\nВыведите список на экран", 
                                           fourth_laboratory_second_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 4 Подзадача 3": ("Пусть журнал по предмету 'Информационные технологии' представлен в " 
                                           "Пусть дан журнал по предмету 'Информационные технологии' " 
                                           "представлен в виде списка my_len." 
                                           "Выведите список студентов конкретной группы построчно в " 
                                           "виде:\n<Название группы>\n\t<ФИО>\n\t<ФИО>", 
                                           fourth_laboratory_third_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 4 Подзадача 4": ("Пусть журнал по предмету 'Информационные технологии' представлен в " 
                                           "виде списка my_len." 
                                           "Выведите всех студентов (и их группы), если фамилия студента " 
                                           "начинается на букву А.", fourth_laboratory_fourth_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 5 Подзадача 1": ("Пусть дана некоторая директория. Посчитайте количество файлов в " 
                                           "данной директории и выведите на экран", fifth_laboratory_first_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 5 Подзадача 2": ("Пусть дан файл students.csv, в котором содержится информация о " 
                                           "студентах в группе \n №;ФИО;Возраст;Группа\nВыведите информацию о " 
                                           "студентах, отсортировав их по фамилии.", fifth_laboratory_second_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 5 Подзадача 3": ("Добавить к задаче 2 пользовательский интерфейс.\nПо увеличению " 
                                           "возраста всех студентов на 1", fifth_laboratory_third_question), 
     "Лабораторная работа 5 Подзадача 4": ("Добавьте к пользовательскому интерфейсу из задачи возможность " 
                                           "сохранения новых данных обратно в файл", fifth_laboratory_fourth_question) 
 } 
  
  
 class TaskChooser: 
     __slots__ = ("number_laboratory", "number_question") 
  
     def __init__(self, number_laboratory: int, number_question: int): 
         self.number_laboratory = number_laboratory 
         self.number_question = number_question 
  
     @property 
     def condition(self): 
         return dictionary.get(f"Лабораторная работа {self.number_laboratory} Подзадача {self.number_question}", 
                               ("Не выполнял ещё", " "))[0] 
  
     @property 
     def function(self): 
         return dictionary.get(f"Лабораторная работа {self.number_laboratory} Подзадача {self.number_question}", 
                               (" ", None))[1]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему. Опубликуйте модули `tabdemo.py` и `tasks.py`

Comment: Приветствую снова, я добавил модули, которые вы попросили предоставить. Изначально, я просто в них толк не видел, потому что настойка визуального окружения происходит в `DlgMain`. Вы до этого создали layout для меню, старался на нём закреплять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не в тот менеджер компоновки вставляете виджеты.

Вы должны создать, например список, экземпляров класса `class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):` и с этим списком работать.

```
import sys
'''
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from tasks import TaskChooser
''' # ??? ?# ??? ?# ??? ?# ??? ?# ??? ?# ??? ?
from programming_languages.first_laba_lang.tutor import first_question as first_laboratory_first_question 
...
'''
second_laboratory_first_question = 'second_laboratory_first_question'
second_laboratory_second_question = '# ??? ?'
second_laboratory_third_question = '# ??? ?' 
second_laboratory_fourth_question = '# ??? ?' 
third_laboratory_first_question = 'third_laboratory_first_question' 
third_laboratory_second_question = ''
third_laboratory_third_question = ''
third_laboratory_fourth_question = ''
fourth_laboratory_first_question = 'fourth_laboratory_first_question'
fourth_laboratory_second_question = ''
fourth_laboratory_third_question = ''
fourth_laboratory_fourth_question = ''
fifth_laboratory_first_question = 'fifth_laboratory_first_question'
fifth_laboratory_second_question = ''
fifth_laboratory_third_question = ''
fifth_laboratory_fourth_question = ''
first_laboratory_first_question = 'first_laboratory_first_question'
first_laboratory_second_question = ''
first_laboratory_third_question = ''
first_laboratory_fourth_question = ''
  
dictionary = { 
    "Лабораторная работа 1 Подзадача 1": ( 
        "Напишите программу для решения примера. Есть переменные: a,b,c,k: Предусмотрите деление на 0. " 
        "\nВсе необходимые переменные вводите ниже. ", first_laboratory_first_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 1 Подзадача 2": ("Дан произвольный список, содержащий и строки, и числа. \n" 
                                          "Выведите все четные элементы построчно. ", first_laboratory_second_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 1 Подзадача 3": ("Дан произвольный список, содержащий только числа. \n " 
                                          "Выведите результат сложения чисел больше 10. ", 
                                          first_laboratory_third_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 1 Подзадача 4": ("Дан произвольный список, содержащий только числа. \n" 
                                          "Выведите максимальное число", first_laboratory_fourth_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 2 Подзадача 1": ("Пусть задано некоторое число my_number. \n" 
                                          "Запрашивайте у пользователя вводить число user_number до тех пор, " 
                                          "пока оно не будет меньше my_number", second_laboratory_first_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 2 Подзадача 2": ("Пусть задан список, содержащий строки. \n" 
                                          "Выведите построчно все строки размером от 5 до 10 символов. ", 
                                          second_laboratory_second_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 2 Подзадача 3": ("Сгенерируйте и выведите случайную строку, состоящую из 5 символов, \n" 
                                          "содержащую только заглавные буквы русского алфавита", 
                                          second_laboratory_third_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 2 Подзадача 4": ("Пусть дана строка. На основе данной строки сформируйте новую, " 
                                          "содержащую только цифры \nВыведите новую строку. ", 
                                          second_laboratory_fourth_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 3 Подзадача 1": ("Пусть дана строка, состоящая из слов, пробелов и знаков препинания. " 
                                          "\n" 
                                          "На основании этой строки создайте новую (и выведите её на консоль) \n" 
                                          "Содержащую только слова больше 5 символов.", 
                                          third_laboratory_first_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 3 Подзадача 2": ("Пусть дана строковая переменная, содержащая информацию о студентах: " 
                                          "\n" 
                                          "my_string='Ф;И;О;Возраст;Категория;_Иванов;Иван;Иванович;23 года'", 
                                          third_laboratory_second_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 3 Подзадача 3": ("Дана строка из прошлого задания. Выведите построчно информацию о " 
                                          "студентах, чья фамилия 'Петров'", third_laboratory_third_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 3 Подзадача 4": ("Пусть дана строка произвольной длины. Выведите информацию о том, " 
                                          "сколько в ней символов и сколько строк.", third_laboratory_fourth_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 4 Подзадача 1": ("Пусть дана матрица чисел размером NxN. Представьте данную матрицу в " 
                                          "виде списка.\nВыведите результат сложения всех элементов матрицы.", 
                                          fourth_laboratory_first_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 4 Подзадача 2": ("Пусть дан список из 10 элементов. Удалите первые 2 элемента и " 
                                          "добавьте 2 новых.\nВыведите список на экран", 
                                          fourth_laboratory_second_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 4 Подзадача 3": ("Пусть журнал по предмету 'Информационные технологии' представлен в " 
                                          "Пусть дан журнал по предмету 'Информационные технологии' " 
                                          "представлен в виде списка my_len." 
                                          "Выведите список студентов конкретной группы построчно в " 
                                          "виде:\n<Название группы>\n\t<ФИО>\n\t<ФИО>", 
                                          fourth_laboratory_third_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 4 Подзадача 4": ("Пусть журнал по предмету 'Информационные технологии' представлен в " 
                                          "виде списка my_len." 
                                          "Выведите всех студентов (и их группы), если фамилия студента " 
                                          "начинается на букву А.", fourth_laboratory_fourth_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 5 Подзадача 1": ("Пусть дана некоторая директория. Посчитайте количество файлов в " 
                                          "данной директории и выведите на экран", fifth_laboratory_first_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 5 Подзадача 2": ("Пусть дан файл students.csv, в котором содержится информация о " 
                                          "студентах в группе \n №;ФИО;Возраст;Группа\nВыведите информацию о " 
                                          "студентах, отсортировав их по фамилии.", fifth_laboratory_second_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 5 Подзадача 3": ("Добавить к задаче 2 пользовательский интерфейс.\nПо увеличению " 
                                          "возраста всех студентов на 1", fifth_laboratory_third_question), 
    "Лабораторная работа 5 Подзадача 4": ("Добавьте к пользовательскому интерфейсу из задачи возможность " 
                                          "сохранения новых данных обратно в файл", fifth_laboratory_fourth_question) 
} 
  
  
class TaskChooser: 
    __slots__ = ("number_laboratory", "number_question") 
  
    def __init__(self, number_laboratory: int, number_question: int): 
        self.number_laboratory = number_laboratory 
        self.number_question = number_question 
  
    @property 
    def condition(self): 
        return dictionary.get(f"Лабораторная работа {self.number_laboratory} Подзадача {self.number_question}", 
                              ("Не выполнял ещё", " "))[0] 
  
    @property 
    def function(self): 
        return dictionary.get(f"Лабораторная работа {self.number_laboratory} Подзадача {self.number_question}", 
                              (" ", None))[1]


#from tabdemo import TabWidget
class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar): 
  
    def tabSizeHint(self, index): 
        s = QtWidgets.QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index) 
        s.transpose() 
        return s 
  
    def paintEvent(self, event): 
        painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self) 
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTab() 
  
        for i in range(self.count()): 
            self.initStyleOption(opt, i) 
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.ControlElement.CE_TabBarTabShape, opt) 
            painter.save() 
  
            s = opt.rect.size() 
            s.transpose() 
            r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), s) 
            r.moveCenter(opt.rect.center()) 
            opt.rect = r 
  
            c = self.tabRect(i).center() 
            painter.translate(c) 
            painter.rotate(90) 
            painter.translate(-c) 
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.ControlElement.CE_TabBarTabLabel, opt) 
            painter.restore() 
  

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, num_lab): 
        super().__init__() 
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self) 

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(f"Лабораторная работа {num_lab}") 
        self.label.setStyleSheet(""" 
            font-size: 24px; 
        """) 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 
            alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter | \
                      QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop) 
        
# +++ 
        self._create_combobox() 
        self._create_question()
        self._create_input_output_data()
        
    def _create_input_output_data(self):
#        self.input_data = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.input_data = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.input_data.setPlaceholderText("Input data: ")

        self.output_data = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.output_data.setPlaceholderText("Output data: ")
        self.output_data.setReadOnly(True)

        splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Vertical)
        splitter.addWidget(self.input_data)
        splitter.addWidget(self.output_data)
# +++
        splitter.setSizes([200, 100])                                     # +++
        self.layout.addWidget(splitter, 3) 
#        alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight)
        
    def _create_question(self):
        """
        Создание места для условия, динамически должен обновляться в зависимости от выбора в combobox и TabWidget
        """
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            "Напишите программу для решения примера. Есть переменные: a,b,c,k: Предусмотрите деление на 0. "
            "\nВсе необходимые переменные вводите ниже.")
# +++
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)                             # +++  
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 2,
            alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignVCenter)
                      
    def _create_combobox(self):
        """ Создание выпадающего списка, 
        предположительно должен находится в правом верхнем угле
        """
        # создание выпадающего списка, гле будут задания
        self.combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()  
        self.combobox.addItems([
            "Задание 1", "Задание 2", 
            "Задание 3", "Задание 4"
        ])  # в каждой лабораторной 4 задания
        self.layout.addWidget(self.combobox, 0,
            alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight | \
                      QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)
 
  
class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None): 
        super().__init__(parent)
# +++
        self.parent = parent                                             # +++

        self.setTabBar(TabBar(self)) 
  
        self.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.TabPosition.West) 
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Cantrell', 11)) 
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self) 

    def create_tabs(self, count): 
        self.parent.list_widget = []                                     # !!! +++
        for i in range(1, count + 1): 
            widget = Widget(i)                                           # !!! +++
            widget.combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(                 # !!! +++
                self.parent._update_condition)                           # !!! +++

            self.addTab(widget, QtGui.QIcon("Ok.png"), 
                f"Лабораторная работа {i}")
            self.parent.list_widget.append(widget)                       # !!! +++


class DlgMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    """
    Главный класс, здесь описывается основное окно, с которым взаимодействуем.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.list_widget = []                                            # !!! +++
        
        self._init_ui()               # установка параметров для прил-я
        self._create_tabs_vertical(6) # созд. кол-ва пунктов в боковом меню
        
#-        self._create_combobox()        
#-        self._create_question()
#-        self._create_input_output_data()

        self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self._update_condition)
#-        self.combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self._update_condition)

    def _init_ui(self):
        """ Метод для инициализации параметров приложения """
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Ковалев Данил ВКБ22")  
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("im.png"))  
        self.resize(800, 500)  
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Cantrell', 11))  
        self._center()       # Центрирование приложение при запуске

    def _center(self):
        """
        Метод, который центрует положения появления окна при запуске.
        """
        qr = self.frameGeometry()          # размеры нашего окна
        cp = QtGui.QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def _create_tabs_vertical(self, n):
        """
        Создание вертикального меню, где находятся лабораторные работы
        """
# !!! +++ ------------------> vvvv <----------------------------------------------
        self.tabs = TabWidget(self)
        self.tabs.create_tabs(n)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)

    def _update_condition(self):
# !!! +++
        widget = self.list_widget[self.tabs.currentIndex()]                # !!! +++
    
        current_laboratory = self.tabs.currentIndex() + 1
#        current_number_question = self.combobox.currentIndex() + 1
        current_number_question = widget.combobox.currentIndex() + 1       # !!! +++
        condition = TaskChooser(current_laboratory, current_number_question).condition
        
#        self.label.setText(condition)
        widget.label.setText(condition)                                    # !!! +++
       
        widget.input_data.clear()                                          # ??? ??? 

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        """
        Диалоговое окно, оно появляется, когда пользователь хочет закрыть приложение
        """
        res = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, 
            "Выход", "Вы точно уверены, что хотите выйти? ")
        event.accept() if res == 16384 else event.ignore()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dlg_window = DlgMain()
    dlg_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]